# How can I playback a network capture through the same machine

Tags: networking, tcpreplay

I've been trying to get `tcpreplay` to work to replay a network capture I have on my system. re. Unfortunately, (from the [FAQ](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/FAQ#RunningTcpreplay)):

> **Can I send packets on the same computer running tcpreplay?**
>
> Generally speaking no. When tcpreplay sends packets, it injects them
>   between the TCP/IP stack of the system and the device driver of the
>   network card. The result is the TCP/IP stack system running tcpreplay
>   never sees the packets.

The FAQ proposes running a virtual machine, but I'd like to avoid that. Is there another tool that could allow me to send the info to the same machine?